# For what values of $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ , $8^{(1+\cos x +|\cos 2x| +\cos 3x +\dots )}=4^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Can anybody please help me on this, I have reached till $$\cos x +|\cos 2x |+\cos 3x +\dots  = 1,$$  now I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: There is a relatively unknown formula for $\sin(x)|\sin(x)| = \frac{8}{3\pi}[\sin(x) - \frac{1}{5}\sin(3x) + \frac{1}{5\times7}\sin(5x) - ...]$ Which I would imagine you can translate by $\pi/2$ if valid? Also try squaring both sides. That'll take away the modulus signs no? You will end up with a mess but hopefully that cleans up quickly

Comment: note: $|\cos(x)| = +\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}$

Comment: The exponent is unclear.  What does $$1+\cos x+|\cos 2x| + \cos 3x +\cdots$$mean??

Comment: @IsmailBello How will squaring both sides "take away the modulus signs?"  $(x^y)^2\ne x^{y^2}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV as in $(x + |y|)^2 = x^2 + 2x|y| + y^2$, ok so there will be a few floating about afterwards... Didnt think that far.

Comment: exponent is sum upto infinity of 1+cos x +|cos 2x|+ cos 3x+..

Comment: How does the series continue????

Comment: next term will be |cos 4x| 
basically terms will be |cos nx| ,if n is even and cos nx otherwise

Comment: I assumed he meant $\sum_{n=1, n \in odd}^{\infty}{\cos(nx) + |\cos(2nx)|}$?

Comment: @IsmailBello You mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos((2n-1)x) +\mid \cos (2nx) \mid $$

Comment: My bad, as @graydad said :)

Comment: are we sure that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos((2n-1)x) +\mid \cos (2nx) \mid$$ converges? Intuitively, I would say that $$\cos((2n-1)x) +\mid \cos (2nx) \mid \not\to 0$$...